# How to make HTML tag take effect automatically in mvc Razor View?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have following type of data stored in my database field

```
&lt;p&gt;sdf&#39;jsdfkl&#39;&#39;jksdl;fj/ sdfjklf&#39;&#39; Hiee&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;dfgdgdgfgsd&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;fsfsfsf&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;dfsfsdff&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;&lt;img src=&quot;../Scripts/tinymce/plugins/emoticons/img/smiley-cool.gif&quot; alt=&quot;&quot; /&gt;&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;Hie this text comes out from TextEditor.. &#39;sf&#39;fsfdfs&#39;df&#39;f&#39;&#39;&quot;&quot;&#39;&quot;sdfsfskfkf/lfdjklsfj\jslfjklff&lt;/p&gt;
```

I have stored it in SQL server in ASP.net C# using HttpUtility.HtmlEncode() method.

Now i want to retrieve that data from database and want to display it without html tags..

For that I have used HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(), but that only decodes and generate tags and generated following result

```
<p>sdf'jsdfkl''jksdl;fj/ sdfjklf'' Hiee</p> <p>&nbsp;</p> <p><strong>dfgdgdgfgsd</strong></p> <p><strong>fsfsfsf</strong></p> <p><strong>dfsfsdff</strong></p> <p>&nbsp;</p> <p><strong><img src="../Scripts/tinymce/plugins/emoticons/img/smiley-cool.gif" alt="" /></strong></p> <p>&nbsp;</p> <p>Hie this text comes out from TextEditor.. 'sf'fsfdfs'df'f''""'"sdfsfskfkf/lfdjklsfj\jslfjklff</p>
```

**I don't want to display all these tags, instead just want to display text, so what should i do??**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Html.Raw()` on view or partial view for display html.

```
Html.Raw("<div class=\"resource-row\">").ToString()
```